# Proving properties of Random Graphs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, random, random-graphs

I am asking the question on a slightly abstract level and it may depend on the specifics but it would be great to have related references or ideas.

Consider the random graph model $G_{n,p}$ where its a random graph on n vertices and each edge is selected with probability $p$. I want to prove that a certain property $P$ is satisfied by graphs in this model with high probability ($\rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$). I know/can prove the following two facts

1. Conditioned on the event that the graph obtained from the sample is regular, the probability of the property being satisfied is very high (something like $1 - 1/n^c$)
2. Given any graph G and any other graph G' that can be obtained by removing edges from G. If G satisfies the property then so does G'.

Can the above two statements be enough to make a general statement about the probability of the satisfaction of the property in $G_{n,p}$

Any references would be very helpful?

Comment: Well, to me it seems that from 1) the complete graph $K_n$ has property $P$ with high probability as $K_n$ is regular.  Then from 2), if $K_n$ has property $P$, then any subgraph (not necessarily induced)  of $K_n$ has property $P$ - that is, all graphs on $n$ vertices.  So if $K_n$ has $P$ with probability 1 as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then any graph on $n$ vertices has $P$ with probability 1 as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: No it is not necessary that the complete graph has the property. 1) only states that most(with respect to their probability mass) regular graphs have the property P. This does not in particular imply that K_n has the property. Your statement makes it seem that the model is not clear enough. K_n is a single graph it either has the property or it does not. There is no probability involved in that. The probability is over the sampling of graphs.